# Launching multiple Kafka brokers fails - Configured brokerId doesn't match stored brokerId

Tags: apache-kafka

While trying to launch multiple Kafka brokers with different brokerId's. One being the default `server.properties` and the other being `serverTest.properties` with 2 lines changed, those being `broker.id=1` and `listeners=PLAINTEXT://localhost:6000`. The rest is the same default setting. I first start zookeeper, then the default kafka `server.properties` then while launching `serverTest.properties` I get the following exception: `kafka.common.InconsistentBrokerIdException: Configured brokerId 1 doesn't match stored brokerId 0 in meta.properties`. My understanding is that the following above should actually launch multiple nodes, as I've seen others do in tutorials.  I'm using Kafka 9.0.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Edit config/serverTest.properties and replace the existing config values as follows:

```
broker.id=2
listeners=PLAINTEXT://9093
log.dirs=/tmp/kafka-logs-2
```

If you want a third broker:

```
cp config/server.properties config/server3.properties
```

Edit config/server3.properties and replace the existing config values as follows:

```
broker.id=3
listeners=PLAINTEXT://:9094
log.dirs=/tmp/kafka-logs-3
```

if you run on different machines you must change

```
advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://192.168.x.x:<port>
```

else if you run in the same vmware machine, for example you should only change the port and log.dir as described above

Comment: My understanding was that `listeners=PLAINTEXT://localhost:6000` should have made it run on part `6000` as well.

Comment: From your edit above, If I do leave the listners alone and just change the port, one test I've done is to go to that port in a web browser. I notice on 9092, Kafka will mention receiving an invalid byte amount, while doing the same with `localhost:6000` does nothing. Im looking to run a kafka broker that can be connected on via port 6000 within the bootstrap settings on the kafka java client.

Comment: Port 6000 is the default port for X Windows so make sure you don't have some other conflict unrelated to Kafka. Best to avoid the entire 6000-6063 range - http://www.networksorcery.com/enp/protocol/xwindow.htm

Comment: I've just noticed that Kafka has a bug - it prints default port 9092 for a broker for which we've modified the server.properties file to point to another port. However, the server i.e. broker opens the port the config mentions. So looks like a logging bug for kafka 2.12

Comment: I am using kafka_2.11-2.3.1 and I cannot file serverTest.properties in the config folder.

Comment: @mnagdev  you can follow this guide it has many details https://kafka.apache.org/quickstart

Answer (score 12):

Speaking from experience, don't forget to edit the `broker.id` entries in the `kafka-logs-*/meta.properties` files to match your changes (or delete the files and let kafka regenerate them).

Answer (score 9):

This is old question, still this answer should help others. The problem is when you create new server.properties from existing server.properties, below line will get copied:

```
# A comma separated list of directories under which to store log files
log.dirs=/tmp/kafka-logs
```

So, even new broker tries to use the same log dir and hence it uses the meta.properties of kafka-logs which is created by broker 0 and has broker id as 0.

So, go to /tmp and delete all kafka-logs* files and then comment `log.dirs=/tmp/kafka-logs` 
and then add the lines as you have added :)

Comment: I think this is the main reason :), because when we follow the tutorial just like listeners we create another entry at the top and the default file already have an entry of `log.dirs`

Answer (score 8):

The answers are perfect but it took me a while to figure it out to get it work. I would like to share my mistake and hope others can avoid it.

I followed the official tutorial with kafka here:

https://kafka.apache.org/quickstart#quickstart_multibroker.

and make a file copy as suggested in the guide:

```
cp config/server.properties config/server-1.properties
```

I open the file using vim. I do a search for **broker.id** and replace with the following(mistake by assuming there is no existing **listeners** and **log.dirs**) as below

```
# config/server-1.properties:
broker.id=1
listeners=PLAINTEXT://:9093
log.dirs=/tmp/kafka-logs-1
```

I started a new broker with

```rb
 >  bin/kafka-server-start.sh config/server-1.properties
```

crashed!!!. This is how I debug:

I went **/tmp** and checked the dir **kafka-logs-1** did not appear. I realized that there should be something wrong with my log.dir in config. I double checked it  in the config/server-1.propeties. I found that there were two lines of log.dirs.

```
#copy from the tutorial
log.dirs=/tmp/kafka-logs-1


# default one
log.dirs=/tmp/kafka-logs
```

Of course the last one overridden the first one thus making the new broker point to the first broker with id=0.

After removing the last log.dirs and keep only one log.dirs ( **log.dirs=/tmp/kafka-logs-1** ) works like a charm.

Comment: Thank you, I had the same issue.

Comment: @ToofanHasArrived yes, seems that it is easy to make a mistake.

Comment: Link is dead...

Answer (score 2):

Make sure in your `server.properties` and `serverTest.properties` you have different `log.dirs`

If you had to make any `log.dirs` changes don't forget to remove previous folders stored on your PC

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the **log directories**, **broker id** and **ports** (with listeners) are different for each node/broker.

> Sample configuration (**server.properties**):

**Broker 1**

```
broker.id=1
listeners=PLAINTEXT://:9092
log.dirs=/tmp/kafka-1-logs
```

**Broker 2**

```
broker.id=2
listeners=PLAINTEXT://:9093
log.dirs=/tmp/kafka-2-logs
```

**Broker 3**

```
broker.id=3
listeners=PLAINTEXT://:9094
log.dirs=/tmp/kafka-3-logs
```

Hope this will help. Happy hacking!!