# How can I startup serveral brokers?

Tags: apache-kafka

I am trying to start up three brokers and in order to do this I create three copies of the properties like following:

I downloaded kafka, and created an env var like this

```
export KAFKA_HOME="/home/tlaloc/Kafka/bin"
export PATH=$KAFKA_HOME:$PATH
```

**Broker 0**

```
 broker.id=0
 port=9092
 log.dir=/tmp/kafka-logs-0
```

**Broker 1**

```
broker.id=1
port=9093
log.dir=/tmp/kafka-logs-1
```

**Broker 2**

```
broker.id=2
port=9094
log.dir=/tmp/kafka-logs-2
```

After this I execute zookeeper with the following default properties:

```
./zookeeper-server-start.sh $KAFKA_HOME/../config/zookeeper.properties
```

And after this I execute the first broker that works perfectly:

```
./kafka-server-start.sh $KAFKA_HOME/../config/*-0.properties
```

But when try to run the second one:

```
./kafka-server-start.sh $KAFKA_HOME/../config/*-2.properties
```

I got the following error message:

> ERROR Fatal error during KafkaServer startup. Prepare to shutdown
> (kafka.server.KafkaServer) kafka.common.InconsistentBrokerIdException:
> Configured broker.id 2 doesn't match stored broker.id Some(0) in
> meta.properties. If you moved your data, make sure your configured
> broker.id matches. If you intend to create a new broker, you should
> remove all data in your data directories (log.dirs).  at
> kafka.server.KafkaServer.getOrGenerateBrokerId(KafkaServer.scala:793)
> at kafka.server.KafkaServer.startup(KafkaServer.scala:226)  at
> kafka.Kafka$.main(Kafka.scala:109)    at kafka.Kafka.main(Kafka.scala)

Why I got this message, how can I solve and run three brokers?

Thanks

Comment: Typo? `log.dirs` is where the data should be stored

Comment: No, unafortunatly is not a type, I watched https://learning.oreilly.com/library/view/apache-kafka-1-0/9781787286849/18e153b7-ebcf-4a64-845d-3228fd271115.xhtml and log.dir is the correct way., I tried anyway but doesn't work.

Comment: That's an old property. Read the error - `remove all data in your data directories (log.dirs)...` . Since two brokers are using the default value, you're output is saying the next broker conflicts with the first - `stored broker.id Some(0) in meta.properties`

Comment: I am triying with log.dirs, and I am doing a rm -rf /tmp/* before each execution, but I got the same error.

Comment: Well, according to the docs, you only need 3 unique properties, [one of which being `log.dirs`](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#brokerconfigs). I see you're missing `zookeeper.connect`.... In any case, I personally haven't tried to run 3 brokers on one host outside of Docker in a few years; there's really no point since it's not truly fault tolerant. Can you explain your use case better? Or are you just trying to follow the O'Reilly docs with a version other than Kafka 1.0?

Comment: Was an error, the first one, is that the logs attribute was overriding in the file, and the second wand is that port is now listeners.

Comment: So, you've fixed it? Sounds like you're having the same problem as this person? https://stackoverflow.com/a/54806115/2308683